# Transmission gate simulation

Tags: mosfet, logic-gates, transmission, bidirectional

When the voltage on node n-mosfet is a Logic 1, the complementary Logic 0 is applied to node active-low n-mosfet, allowing both transistors to conduct and pass the signal at IN to OUT. When the voltage on node active-low n-mosfet is a Logic 0, the complementary Logic 1 is applied to node n-mosfet, turning both transistors off and forcing a high-impedance condition on both the IN and OUT nodes, but that not the case here, the output behaves independent of what happens at the gates. I expect to have zero voltage at the out put when the voltage at the p-mosfet is high. 
Am i doing something wrong? [image]

Comment: What voltage levels are you running? A mosfet needs a minimum threshold at the gate to work.

Comment: Also, the bulk nodes may need to be properly connected, 3-terminal mosfets are not symmetrical devices.

Comment: @SvenB The threshold voltage is 1[V] the clock and AC source are running above this threshold voltage say 2.5 [V] and 5 [V].
I have only three terminals i can't change the component. I think the bulk is connected internally to the gate i ain't really sure.

Comment: Is the right component (blue) a voltage source by any chance? I didn't see at first because of the highlight. In that case the right voltage is fixed by the voltage source, while the left voltage is fixed to 0V by the ground connection and you won't see any effect.

Comment: @SvenB The highlighted segment is just a piece of wire, but right onder it yes there is AC voltage source. 
I'm going to use this transmission gate to build a sample and hold circuit. Could you please  explain more because i don't see wha i do wrong.

Comment: Your schematic will close a switch between ground and a voltage source. You won't see anything because both voltages are fixed. Connect a resistor between ground and the TG and measure the voltage across that.